# Knockoutjs: What do you use for $item to reference item in a foreach?

Tags: knockout.js

If you do this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
        <em data-bind="if: manufacturer">
            &mdash; made by <span data-bind="text: manufacturer.company"></span>
        </em>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It works without a template (or engine.)  However, how do you reference the individual item?  In jQuery Tmpl, it was $item.  What is it in Knockoutjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $data to reference the current item.  You can use $parent to reference the data for one scope level up and $root to reference the top level view model.